Eclipse cannot connect to internet even with correct proxy settings
I know how to configure proxy settings:

I've successfully configured my Linux VM to use my company's proxy settings.
I've also manually set the proxy values on command line for pip in Windows.

The following is for Windows environment.
In both the Eclipse installer and Eclipse itself, I set the proxy settings but it cannot access the internet.
I'm suspecting the Eclipse code may be faulty.
What other steps can I take to make Eclipse connect?
Eclipse Installer on Windows:
...
    Adding metadata repository https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/22/updates/release/latest
Adding metadata repository https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1006 Unknown Host: https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/content.xml
java.net.UnknownHostException: download.eclipse.org
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:43)
...

To prove to myself that I know how to configure a proxy, I ran the following pip command in Windows (I removed the actual details):
pip install requests --dry-run --proxy http://<user>:<password>@<url>:<port>

And it worked:
C:\Python\Python312\Scripts>pip install requests --dry-run --proxy http://<user>:<password>@<url>:<port>
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached urllib3-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Using cached certifi-2024.6.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Using cached requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Using cached certifi-2024.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (164 kB)
Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (100 kB)
Using cached idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Using cached urllib3-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Would install certifi-2024.6.2 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 idna-3.7 requests-2.32.3 urllib3-2.2.2

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.0 -> 24.1.1
[notice] To update, run: C:\Python\Python312\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

In Eclipse:


Are other applications, specifically curl and pip, able to connect from within the VM? "Unknown Host" looks more like a DNS issue in your VM's setup.

@nitind updated: this is happening on Windows

Unless that also means the error message is different, it doesn't matter.

I suspect that you have done something wrong since it works for others. Please tell us exactly what you have done. Be aware that there are often different ways of doing things.

In Eclipse, when I cleared the entry for socks, everything worked.
